# How do you hyphenate 'day to day'?

Tags: word-usage

Should I use the spelling (and punctuation) 'day-to-day', 'month-to-month', and 'year-to-year' or 'day to day', 'month to month', and 'year to year'?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. What has your research turned up?

Answer (score 8):

Context is key.

You use hyphens when the compound words are really a single word that don't make sense by themselves. Suppose "month to month" modifies another word, as in:

> My lease is up, so now I'm on the month-to-month portion of the contract.

You should hyphenate *month-to-month* because it becomes an indivisible adjective to describe *portion*. (You could not say, for example, * *month portion of the contract* or * *month to portion of the contract*. You could not say these because the compound words *month-to-month* are tied together in meaning.)

Similarly,

> I'm eking out a meager day-to-day existence.

In contrast, for the sentence

> I'm living from day to day.

no hyphens are needed, as there's no word being modified by *day to day*.

A helpful reference would be the *Chicago Manual of Style*, and their Table 6.1 ("A spelling guide for compound words.") I'm reading from the ancient and venerable 13th ed.